# Local Video File loop tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos

I'm attempting to play a simple local clip in Xcode7 using Swift for tvOS. All I want is for the video to load fullscreen in the view and loop. Every tutorial I see has the old `MPMoviePlayerController` or loads from a URL. What is the best way to do this on tvOS?

Update2: This got the video to loop but there is a pause in between. looking into it now to see how to do it seamlessly.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation



class ViewController: UIViewController {



var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
    self.playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
    self.videoPlayer!.play()

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)






    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidReachEnd:"), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
    }






    func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
        self.videoPlayer.play()
    }




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your file is named `video.m4v` and is stored locally on the device (don't forget to add it to Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases). Create a stored property so you can access the `AVPlayer-instance`:

```
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer?
```

Setup the video player and add the `AVPlayerLayer` to your view hierarchy.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"m4v") {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
    self.playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidReachEnd:"), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
}
```

You have now subscribed a notification that i sent when this video ends. Implement handler and tell the player to replay video.

```
func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.videoPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: Updated my code above. Plays but still will not loop. Thanks in advance for anymore help

Comment: Are you saying this will not loop at all or are you saying there is a small gap between the ending and start of the video?

Comment: There is a small gap. I made another thread about it and apparently having it seamless is impossible with AVPlayer

Comment: Yes so I have heard. A kind of awkward way (and I don't know if this fits your project), is to have 2 AVPlayers in the view hierarchy and when the first one finishes you switch to the second one and bring it to the front.